# Networking within the music community

Tags: performing

I know this question may not fit with the standards set by the moderators of this site but I ask anyway because I need help. Please don't suspend me for this.

I have been playing music for quite sometime and have gotten to the point where
I am sick of playing by myself in my room.

I live on Long Island and have no friends (really).

I have no friends who play music and have never really known anyone with my interests.

I want to know if anyone knows of any places or communities maybe on the internet or in NYC.

I know of places that host open mics and jam sessions but I am looking for fellow musicians to meet and connect with maybe start a band with.

I would like to play in a guitar duo or band. I play blues, rock, jazz really anything just to get experience.

I really want to start playing with other musicians so badly.

I guess my question is how in your opinion can I go about finding musicians to network with and start a project with a band or duo with.

Should I go to more jam sessions?

Are there websites for networking musically?

I have posted an ad on craig's list but only got one reply.

What should I do to make musician friends and partners?

What should I do to find musicians I can play seriously with you know like be involved in a project a band or jazz guitar duo or something?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is a dupe. Will have a look once I get back to a computer.

Comment: The standards are set by the community, not just the mods. The moderators are human exception handlers.

Comment: @DrMayhem http://music.stackexchange.com/q/7276/1678?

Answer (score 2):

When you go to jam sessions, talk to others and ask if they'd be interested in playing with you.  Post more than once on craigslist.  Search [Meetup](http://www.meetup.com) for music and/or guitar meetups in your area.

Following are some NYC-area specific organizations that offer the opportunity for musicians to get together in more or less structured environments.   They do cost some $, but they give you a chance to meet other developing musicians and play in ensembles, often with a teacher/leader.

### For Jazz

- [New York Jazz Academy](http://www.nyjazzacademy.com/) (they have workshops on Long Island and in Queens)
- [New York Jazz Workshop](http://www.newyorkjazzworkshop.com/)
- [SOJ Jazz Center at the Collective](http://thecollective.edu/542/SOJ_Jazz)
- [Lucy Moses School](http://www.kaufmanmusiccenter.org/lms/advanced-search)   (Search under Music->Jazz)

All the above offer workshops and ensembles - the first two especially have different ensembles you can try to get into.

(Also, if you think you're really good, many jazz clubs in the city have jam sessions, often late at night. The level tends to be quite high though.)

### For Rock

- [The Jam NYC](http://www.thejamnyc.com/) (Jam sessions and networking - chance to form your own band)
- [The Studio](http://www.thestudio.org/) (Structured workshops and jam sessions, and probably the chance to network as well)